# How to correctly track Google Analytics inbounds from social channel

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

We have this case:

- a link from the website is shared as a post on a social media
  platform like LinkedIn
- when the user clicks that link he is directed on the website; from
  there he/she clicks another link in order to go on the page with a
  contact form
- the user fills in the contact form and submits it

We track all of this as "page views" but for some reason the inbounds on the contact page appear as coming through the "Direct" channel, not "Social" or any other. Is it possible to know which inbounds come from the Social channel in a case like this one?

Comment: Is this website a single page app ?

Comment: @Kola No, it's a website with multiple pages

Comment: Google Analytics should attributed social referrals automatically based on the `referer` header.   Some users may have their browsers configured not to send that header.   Some redirects (meta refresh redirects) may strip that header.   Otherwise you should see that header for the vast majority of users and GA should be paying attention to it.

Answer (score 1):

When posting links to direct people to your site, you should use query strings to assign extra data. This is called Campaign Parameterisation, or Campaign Tagging.

There are three parameters you should always add:

- `utm_medium` - The marketing channel (social, email, cpc, etc.)
- `utm_source` - The advertiser/site/publication in question (facebook, outbrain, bing, etc.)
- `utm_campaign` - The name of the Camapign that this link is a part of (summersale, newsletter, etc.)

There are two more you can add if you need them:

- `utm_term` - Paid Search only. The Keyword.
- `utm_content` - Used to differentiate between tags (body1, creative3, etc.)

Google Analytics has a URL builder you can use that will make this very simple:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

Comment: It isn't clear that this will work.   This is only possible when you control the link that is posted.   The user says that the links are posted on LinkedIn.   They may not be doing the posting themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Always put some query string attached to social posts like "utm_source", "utm_campaign" and whenever user visit site, assign random identifier in session and using all these data, you can accurately track conversions from social sources.

example: `https://www.example.com/2016/06/04/how-to-track-social-media-campaign?utm_source=linkedin&utm_campaign=promo`

Answer (score 0):

Use google's URL generator to track your social media campaigns.

[Google URL Generator](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this is a useful answer?